# Thread Argument Problem

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have working on multithreaded application I am passing `IMAGETHREADINFO` structure in thread here `nSock` is showing garbage value. What is the problem here.pointer to `IMAGETHREADINFO` is declared as member variable of `CServerConnectionMgr` class.

```
typedef struct
{
    int nScok;
    CServerConnectionMgr* pConMgr;

}IMAGETHREADINFO;
void StartImageThread(SOCKET nSock)
{
stThreadInfo = new IMAGETHREADINFO;
stThreadInfo.pConMgr = this;
stThreadInfo.nScok = nSock;

m_hRecordImageThread = CreateThread (   NULL,0,         (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)StreamImageThread,(void*)&stThreadInfo, 0,&m_nRecordImageThreadID);                                                                                                                                             
if ( NULL == m_hRecordImageThread)
{
   return;
} 
int CServerConnectionMgr::StreamImageThread(void *args)
{   

    IMAGETHREADINFO *pImageThreadInfo = (IMAGETHREADINFO*)&args;

}
```

1. This is variable `pImageThreadInfo->nSock` showing some garbage value
2. This `pImageThreadInfo->pConMgr` is coming correctly

I this is showing wrong value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(void*)&stThreadInfo` is a pointer to the `stThreadInfo` pointer. You likely want to remove the `&`

And then, also change `IMAGETHREADINFO *pImageThreadInfo = (IMAGETHREADINFO*)&args;`, remove the `&`